# Facebook notification link to website

Tags: facebook

I would like to send a user directly to my website from the notification tab. 
Is that possible? 
If not what could be the workaround to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Notifications API is only for Apps on facebook.com: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/notifications

So it is not possible (and not allowed) to use the notification system for external websites.

The only "workaround" is to use the Send Dialog to let Users send your website link to his friends.